# Linker removing static initialiser

Tags: c++

The framework I'm using has changed it's build process, and I've noticed my old strategy for initialising a factory function is failing.  There's a new linking step where the framework makes an intermediate library.

I have a factory and some CPP files containing UI classes that might be required at run time.

A UI class CPP file might end with a line:

```
static FactoryRegister<SomeObject> regSomeObject{"some_object_id"};
```

The FactoryRegister constructor registers the object type with the provided string as an ID, so when the UI is built we can grab all the UI widgets by name.

Since the changes to the framework the constructor of regSomeObject is no longer being called.   I'm guessing the linking thinks the whole thing is dead code and has optimised it all away for me.  Was my registration strategy dumb to start with?  What's a good approach?

(This is on OSX using Xcode tools - the Windows version works fine still!)

Comment: "I'm guessing the linking thinks the whole thing is dead code and has optimised it all away" - don't guess, *know/verify*. Look at the final assembly and you will know if that's the case.

Comment: Why can't you register them when they are actually needed i.e. instantiated?

Comment: The good approach is to never rely on dynamic initialization stage. As a workaround you can link intermediate libraries using `--whole-archive` linker option (or whatever equivalent your current toolchain offers).

Comment: Well, if I put a breakpoint on it it never gets hit.   It's a good point though - presumably some otool parameter will tell me...

Comment: @user2672165 it improved build speed to organise things like this.  they could be registered when needed but then the UI code would need a header file for each UI widget and it's a big change.

Comment: @JesperJuhl - yep nm -a on the final product indicates the object is missing but is in the intermediate library.

Comment: @n.m. - If *nothing else* is used from a translation unit, it will be included when linked as an object file but skipped if part of a library.

Comment: Cheers Bo, that's useful insight...so I guess my strategy wasn't crazy if i knew for sure it was never going to be used in a library.

Comment: @BoPersson sorry you are right

Comment: It can be used in a library **if** it's a shared library **or** you use some advanced linker options like `-whole-archive`.